# virt-manager windows 10 guest usb passthrough logitech brio webcam

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, webcam, virt-manager

here is my setup:

- host: ubuntu 21.04
- libvirt: v7.0.0
- guest: windows 10 pro N (version 21H1, OS build 19043.1083)

i am trying to connect my logitech brio webcam to the guest machine. i set up the machine using virt-manager

what i have tried:

- connect to the host machine via usb 3.1 port
- i also have a usb splitter attached to the other 3.1 port that holds the keyboard, mouse and mic inputs
- virt-manager --> info --> add hardware --> USB host device --> logitech brio (002:004)
- i have tried this while the guest is running, rebooting, and adding it while off before booting it up - none of them had any effect
- i also saw [this thread](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1135488) which advised removing unused devices which also did not help (i removed tablet and optical drive)

what happened:

- windows detects the device and installs drivers
- in device manager it shows logitech brio webcam and says it is functioning normally with the latest drivers
- in the windows camera app it detects the camera (and initiates the webcam light indicating it is in use) but the preview window is all black
- when taking a picture: error code `0xA00F4292<PhotoCaptureStartTimeout>`
- when recording a video: it seems to record (preview is still black)
- when playing back the video: `Error Unsupported video type or invalid file path`

any advice on how to proceed? i need to use the VM for work to run windows-only camera software.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a bit late, but I have created a bug ticket on Qemu that addresses your issue: https://gitlab.com/qemu-project/qemu/-/issues/1613